# Types supported in freebase API

Tags: freebase

I have implemented freebase API and want to know the different types supported by google freebase API like (music, university, country, etc). Want to get the complete list of types supported.

Answer (score 0):

The Freebase types are all published on its web site.  You can go to https://www.freebase.com/browse to see all the domains or go to a specific domain like https://www.freebase.com/music or https://www.freebase.com/education?schema=.

You can also look up a particular topic such as University and see what its [equivalent type](https://www.freebase.com/m/07tf8#/freebase/equivalent_topic) is.